# How to remove a widget from the sidebar on specific page?

Tags: widgets, sidebar

I want to remove a widget from page with id '28'. How can I do it?

I have found function for it, but it is private function, so I can't use it.

"wp set sidebars widgets

This function's access is marked as private."

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_sidebars_widgets

Comment: There are plugins for that. Jetpack has widgets visibility feature, and there are [resources](https://www.google.com/search?q=page+specific+widget+wordpress) explaining the issue. Why not research a bit before asking?

Comment: I want to write a plugin for page with id 28. Plugin has 100 lines of code, I hope to do it with 5-6.

Answer (score 2):

```
function my_theme_sidebars_widgets( $sidebars_widgets ) {

if(is_page(28))
    $sidebars_widgets['sidebar-10'][2] = null;

return $sidebars_widgets;
}
add_filter( 'sidebars_widgets', 'my_theme_sidebars_widgets' );
```

ok, I have found a filter for it. I hope this 'null' is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one below.

```
add_filter( 'widget_display_callback', 'hide_widget', 50, 3 );

function hide_widget( $instance, $widget, $args ){
    if ( is_page( 28 ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    return $instance;
}
```

I hope this will be very helpful.